# Python in EV3 - What modules are installed?

Tags: micropython, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I have specific question. I have lego EV3 and i installed Micropython. But i want import turtle, tkinter and other modules and they aren't in micropython. But time module working.Do someone know what modules are in ev3 micropython? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Stackoverflow. MicroPython is very specific to the board it has been ported to run on. There are both standard libraries and hardware specific libraries in your MicroPython port and then open-source libraries you can install.  I bet MOST of the Python and MicroPython specific libraries will be in your image. More on Libraries here:  http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/index.html

I did not see any online documentation for Lego's MicroPython version online. If you can find it, it may have this information. If so, please post back the link in the comments.

In the absence of good documentation you can discover what is available using `help()`.

From the link above...

> On some ports you are able to discover the available, built-in libraries that can be imported by entering the following at the REPL:
>
> help('modules')

Your other question is will every Python library work on MicroPython? No. Most will not. You can search for libraries which will work on https://libraries.io. Just be sure to use the filters to narrow the results to MicroPython libraries.

Comment: This seems to be re-iterating exactly what I said in my answer.

Comment: My answer is more complete, offers an answer and directs them on further learning and doesn't start off by insulting the person asking the question by saying "If you are in fact running micropython..."

Comment: Thanks, first link is usefull and I was looking for something like this.

Comment: @Tom be sure and mark one of these as the Answer. It helps others when their searching to know it worked for you.

Comment: LEGO EV3 MicroPython v2.0 docs: https://pybricks.github.io/ev3-micropython/

Answer (score 1):

If you are in fact running [micropython](https://micropython.org/), you're probably not going to find any of those modules. It has "micro" in the name of a reason; while it supports a great deal of Python 3 syntax, it is not fully compatible with C python and most modules not written explicitly for micropython won't work.

You can get a list of built-in modules by running `help("modules")`, and you can see any modules installed on the filesystem using `os.listdir()`.

Comment: The Lego board does support MicroPython.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I left this answer :).